# Python 3 & Django Rest Framework - how to query M-1-M models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model, django-queryset

I have these models:

- Organisation
- Student
- Course
- Enrollment

A Student belongs to an Organisation

A Student can enrol on 1 or more courses

So an Enrollment record basically consists of a given Course and a given Student

```
class Organisation(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Student(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  organisation = models.ForeignKey(to=Organisation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.email

class Course(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  language = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  level = models.CharField(max_length=2)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.language + ' ' + self.level

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ("language", "level")

class Enrollment(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  course = models.ForeignKey(to=Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False)
  student = models.ForeignKey(to=Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False)
  enrolled = models.DateTimeField()
  last_booking = models.DateTimeField()
  credits_total = models.SmallIntegerField(default=10)
  credits_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Given an Organisation ID, I understand that I can get the enrollments for a single student, like so:

```
o=Organisation.objects.get(id=1)
o.student_set.all()[0].enrollment_set.all()
```

but how can I retrieve ALL Enrollments for a given Organisation?

For example, if I wanted to count how many students from a given organisation have enrolled on courses? Something like this:

```
o.student_set.enrollment_set.count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query in reverse, with:

```
Enrollment.objects.filter(student__organisation=o).count()
```

or even without first fetching the `Organization`:

```
Enrollment.objects.filter(student__organisation__id=1).count()
```